# Is it possible to make the entire program without any hard-coded parts?

Tags: design-patterns, argv

Usually when we want to make a program that can be modified without re-compiling process, we read data and configurations from a file.

But this means that somewhere in the code, we must hard-code the file location of data or config file.

For example:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        AppData appData = ReadAppData("app.data");
        AppConfig appConfig = ReadAppConfig("config.txt");
        Program = new Program(appData, appConfig).Run();
    }
}
```

In this case, two strings - "app.data" and "config.txt" - are hard-coded because it is impossible to read files without specifying the file location.

Of course, we can reduce it to one file - for example, we can read only "app.data" and get the configuration file location from that file, but we still cannot remove all hard-coded parts in our program.

Is it theoretically possible to make the entire (useful) program with zero hard-coded parts?

Is it possible to make the entire (useful) program only with soft coding?

Comment: *Please don't give me answers like ...* That is really dependent of how you ask the question. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You only want to omit the configurations and environment dependence things or do you also care for hard-coding of the concrete implementation and just have your code depend on abstractions where Each class exposes or consumes some abstraction. There needs to be a part of the code which does the wiring, this part may be part of the framework but it has to be there. Now for the configurations, environment, you can have your configurations files in a directory whose path you can provide in the cmd line args. The answers below highlight the same in details.

Answer (score 2):

Use command line arguments to pass in the filenames. Your definition for main is incomplete.

In C# this is what your `main` can look like: `static void Main(string[] args)`.

When you call the program you can use `myprogram app.data config.txt`. and your program can get the two arguments from the `args` array. Most programming languages have this type of feature.

You can also return values to the operating system from main. In C# your main declaration would be `static int Main(string[] args)`

`void Main()` is just a shorthand for *"we do not need input"*.

Answer (score 0):

`main` can be written `public static void main(String[] args)` where `args` is an array of white space separated tokens available on `System.in`. That is to say you could write:

```
java softie.java app.data config.txt
```

to the command line and then read `args[0]` and `args[1]` within main enabling you to go:

```
java softie.java otherapp.data otherconfig.txt
```

`System.in` is famous as the command line input but its just a `FileInputStream` that can be available in numerous java calling contexts.